# html images not loading unless full filepath is used

Tags: html

I originally transferred this project from windows to linux, and it was working completely fine on windows, but now images are not loading.

I have an image:

```
<img src="/assets/s1.png" alt="dinosaur">
```

And it is only loading on the webpage if I change the filepath to `/home/user/Desktop/Project/assets/s1.png`

The image file is in the folder `assets` and the assets folder and html file are both within the `Project` folder.

The weird thing is that when I change `/home/user/Desktop/Project/assets/s1.png` to `/Desktop/Project/assets/s1.png` it stops working. I would like to be able to only include the necessary path `/assets/s1.png` because I will need the path to stay the same if this project gets moved around between environments.

Comment: What folder is your HTTP server of choice configured to serve out of? Are you even using any HTTP server? Why not just use relative references, e.g. `./assets/s1.png`...?

Comment: When you open the web page, what is the address of that page in the browser?

Comment: @David I am currently running this locally, so the address of the page is file:///home/user/Desktop/Project/file.tpl (using a template file because eventually this html will be used with python and hosted on local server 8080, but I want to make sure the images are working before I do that because I am having other issues with python and css showing up)

Comment: @breepav: Then that's the problem.  The "root" of the "web server" is the root of your file system.  So if you want to use an absolute path then it has to be the complete path.  You can change the image references to be a relative path instead.  Or change your test to include hosting it on a web server with the root path you want to use.

Comment: @esqew, not sure if this is answering your question, but my goal is to use relative references, but they are not working and I'm not sure why. the relative references work on windows but it's not running on linux (not sure if it has something to do with it being a virtual machine). right now I am not using a server, just running it locally

Comment: @David thank you! I'm starting to understand a lot better. what would it look like if I were to use a relative path instead?

Comment: @breepav: Just like in the first comment on the question.  Something like: `<img src="./assets/s1.png" alt="dinosaur">`  This is mostly a guess on our part, making assumptions about the folder structure.  But if the `assets` folder and the HTML file are in the same directory, this should be a working relative path.  However, be aware that using a file system *at all* for this kind of testing is highly discouraged.  If the plan is to load this page from a web server (and why wouldn't it be) then you should test exactly that. Making changes to get it to work on a file system just complicates it.

Comment: @David thank you so much, that worked. I appreciate the advice about testing, I will definitely stick to testing using servers instead of the file system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a comment on the question:

> the address of the page is file:///home/user/Desktop/Project/file.tpl

That's the problem then.  The "root" of the "web server" (from the browser's perspective) is the root of the file system.  So this absolute path won't work:

```
<img src="/assets/s1.png" alt="dinosaur">
```

But this one will:

```
<img src="/home/user/Desktop/Project/assets/s1.png" alt="dinosaur">
```

However, that latter one clearly won't be helpful in a web-hosted environment.

You can instead use a relative path, for example:

```
<img src="./assets/s1.png" alt="dinosaur">
```

This should work in the example given, but we can't know if this will have further implications in a larger and more complex web application.  For example, if you're dynamically loading sections or templates from different folders, their "relative paths" may be different.  (That's one advantage of absolute paths, they're the same regardless of what page you're on.)

But more to the root cause of the problem... You *really shouldn't* be testing a web page from the file system.  The intent is to host it on a web server, so the testing should be hosted on a web server.

It makes little sense to make changes to the code in order to get it to work in an environment that will never be used, only to probably have to make more changes to get it to work in the actual target environment.  Keep the test environment and the target environment as similar as possible.